# Passing Paramer into MySQL Query - VB6

Tags: mysql, parameters, vb6

I need some help with passing a parameter to a MySQL database table query. I have multiple unique tables which I need to query depending on the "**client***" parameter.

In order to avoid writing endless if statements, I need a way to pass each unique client parameter .i.e **"client1_"** to the database query below. So instead of hard coding the **"client1_accounts"** etc in the query below each time, I need a way to be able to just attach the "client*" parameter to sections of the query where required and avoid writing an if statement as the parameter for each instance will be declared.

```
If tablePrefix = "client1_" Then
    Set myconn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs_client1_accounts = New ADODB.Recordset
    myconn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};server=" & frmSettings.Text1(0).Text & ";uid=" & frmSettings.Text1(2).Text & ";pwd=" & frmSettings.Text1(3).Text & ";database=" & frmSettings.Text1(1).Text & ""
    
    mysql = "SELECT * FROM client1_accounts"
    rs_client1_accounts.Open mysql, myconn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic
        
    Do Until rs_client1_accounts.EOF = True
        List1.AddItem rs_client1_accounts!account
        rs_client1_accounts.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    ElseIf tablePrefix = "client2_ Then
    
    .... etc ... etc
End if
```

I hope I've explained properly what I want to do but if I haven't please ask any question and I'll do my best to clarify.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just write it as a function and pass in "Client_1 as an argument. That said a table for each client was not a good idea, you might want to rework your db so you can do something like Select * From Clients Where ClientId = 'Client1'.

Comment: Hello @TonyHopkinson - Thank you for your reply sir, I'm not sure how to go about this. Kindly show me how. Also, each client has their own unique set of tables which keeps them separate from others. It's how I was told it should be done. I do however appreciate your suggestion may be better.

Comment: Hi @TonyHopkinson - I've decided to rework db as you suggested. I was trying to do this as requested but see there is a better way - your way. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
mysql = "SELECT * FROM client1_accounts"
```

use

```
mysql = "SELECT * FROM " & tablePrefix & "accounts"
```

The result of the second example is a string concatenation identical to the string in the first example.